# What is the default object namespace for functions in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, under what object/namespace do my functions live? In the browser this is 'window'. I thought it was 'global' in node but that doesn't seem to work.

```
function myfunc() {
    console.log('hello');
}

console.log(global.myfunc); // undefined
```

Comment: By default the variables/functions declared in the top level is scoped to the current module. Implicitly it is not added as a property of the `global` object, you need to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Each file in `Node` lives inside it's own context (called module), so the function is "registered" on the module context.

`global` is a context that is common between modules, in order to "register" on it, you need to assign a property on the `global` object.

```js
global.myFunc = function () {};
```

Comment: so I guess for functions it doesn't automatically go into an object like it does with 'window' in the browser.

Comment: any declaration (variable / function) won't be accessible outside the "module" (the file it self) therefore there is `module.exports` & `require` for allowing share between modules

Answer (score -2):

In both browser & nodejs , there's no need to use `window` or `global`, just calling the function name will work.